# Why jQuery "bind" and "on" execute always, where "addEventListener" doesn't?

Tags: jquery

My intention is to have code execute once at "window load" and again every time a "resize" event is triggered.

The jQuery event listeners, both the "load" and "resize", execute on page load without resizing the window.

While the "addEventListener" code executes as expected.
The "load" code executes on load.
The "resize" code executes on resizing the window.

Can someone explain why please? And what would be the solution for jQuery?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $('window').bind('load', alert("Loaded Bind!"));
    $('window').bind('resize', alert("Resized Bind!"));

    $('window').on('load', alert("Loaded On!"));
    $('window').on('resize', alert("Resized On!"));


    window.addEventListener('load',onLoadAlert);
    window.addEventListener('resize',onResizeAlert);

    function onLoadAlert(){alert("Loaded No JQ")}
    function onResizeAlert(){alert("Resize No JQ")}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make your tests cases equivalent. The first four call `alert`, while the last two pass in a function object. This has nothing to do with `addEventListener` vs `on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert is executed immediately and the return from the alert is bound as the listener.... (`undefined` so nothing is bound), you will need to use the handlers as you do in `.addEventListener`:

```
$(window).bind('load', onLoadAlert);
$(window).bind('resize', onResizeAlert);

$(window).on('load', onLoadAlert);
$(window).on('resize', onResizeAlert);
```

This will make the tests equal and the result will become the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added 4 more functions and passed them like you suggested, but the result is that they never execute
[Pastebin Code](http://pastebin.com/ND3qrsXA) ?

Comment: @Deithrian Instead, set a jsFiddle, don't use Pastebin to share sample snippet

Comment: There is no element of type `window`, `window` is a object, use `$(window).on('load', handler);` e.g  http://jsfiddle.net/msu9namc/

Comment: Thank you A. Wolff! Hopefully dev-null can correct the ('window') in the answer.